# Network connection not working for a long time after phone switches to other access point in Asus AiMesh network

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, asus, mesh-networking

I have three Asus RT-AC66U B1 routers with the latest firmware setup with AiMesh.

[image: 1690813201585.png]

One is the main router and the other two "should be" setup in bridge mode. There are no switches between the main router and the nodes and they are setup with ethernet backhaul. I have enabled both 2.4 and 5 GHz, automatic channel selection and all ssid's and passwords are the same.

I made this javascript code that every 300ms fetches some data from dummyjson.com and displays the time it took to fetch the data.

https://jsfiddle.net/mronnlun/vk28pzua/6/show

When I run this on my laptop or phone I see that data is returned in about 200ms.

When my laptop is switching from one access point to another I see a delay of about 2 seconds, e.g. the request to dummyjson takes 2.2 seconds.

When my iPhone 13 Pro running Chrome changes access point I see one request taking 39xxx ms and then it goes back to about 200ms.

I tried it with a Samsung A32 Android phone and when that changes access point the network doesn't recover but you have to switch wifi off and back on to get connectivity back.

What could be the problem?